# How to drag event from v-calendar to outside

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vcalendar

I have a v-calendars and datatable,and

I need to drag an event from calendar to datatable.

It seems I cant drag an event outside the boundary of a calendar.
i am using vuetify 2 calendar.

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? Got any errors? Any emitted events? Some minimal effort is required from your side.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.